# Acronym list not displayed

Tags: acronyms, overleaf

Good afternoon. I'm a new user of Overleaf. I am trying to add an acronym list, but even though the acronyms in the middle of the text work fine, the list is always displayed as an empty page.

I am using a template that my university developed, so I'm not sure what is messing with this list.

Starting .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{report} 

\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{feupteses}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % font times
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdflscape}[2016/05/14]
\usepackage{array, caption, floatrow, tabularx, makecell, booktabs, siunitx,longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}


\newenvironment{myitemize}
{ \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt} }
{ \end{enumerate}} 

\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

%%%%
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ev}{EV}{Electric Vehicles}
%%%%

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\include{mymacros}



%---------------Cover----------------%

\newpage
\begin{framed}
\vspace*{75mm} 
\begin{center} 
\huge \textbf{M} 
\end{center} 
\vspace*{3mm}
\begin{center}
\Large \textit{John}
\end{center}
\vspace*{6mm}
\begin{center}
\large \textbf{M} \\ \vspace*{2mm}
Supervisor:M\\

\vspace*{10mm}
% \begin{figure}[!ht] \center
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{something.pdf}
% \end{figure}

\Large \textbf{M}\\
\vspace*{5mm}
\large 2019-06-DD
\vspace*{5mm}
\end{center}
\end{framed}
\newpage
%-------------Preliminary------------%
\pagestyle{plain}
%\StartPrelim
\begin{singlespace}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{0_abstract} % the abstract
\include{0_acknows} % the acknowledgments
\include{0_quote} % initial quotation if desired
\cleardoublepage
\begin{spacing}{0.98}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
\include{0_abbrevs} % the list of abbreviations used %HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO ADD MY LIST
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{List of Figures}{figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{List of Tables}{tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\end{singlespace}

%-------------Chapters---------------%
%\StartBody
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{1_intro}
\include{2_lreview}
\include{3_description}
\include{4_method}
\include{5_results}
\include{6_discussion}

%------------Bibliography------------%
\begin{singlespace}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{7_bibliography}
\end{singlespace}
%------------------------------------%

%---------Appendices-----------------%
\begin{singlespace}
\appendix
\include{A_Appendix1}
\include{A_Appendix2}
\end{singlespace}
%----------Appendices----------------%

\end{document}
```

The .tex file where i want to add my list:

```
CODE: [SELECT ALL] [EXPAND/COLLAPSE] [DOWNLOAD] ({UNTITLED.TEX}) OPEN IN OVERLEAF
\chapter*{Acronyms and Symbols}
\chaptermark{Acronyms and Symbols}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you used any of the defined acronyms in your main text with e.g.  `\gls{ev}`? Only acronyms (and glossary terms) that have actually been used, will be printed in the list of acronyms in the output. If this is hard to debug, you may want to contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, so that the support team (disclaimer: I'm one such team member) can have a look directly.

Comment: This has been posted on [LaTeX.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=32604) as well.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thank you for your help. I've used ```\acrfull{ev}``` instead, but even with ```\gls{ev}```, even though in the middle of the text the entire definition appears, the list is still empty.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a latexmkrc issue in your project. I would suggest that you contact support@overleaf.com with your project ID, so that the support team can debug your project directly.

Comment: who ever developed this template should clean it up. Throwing every imaginable package (and some of them twice) in the preamble is bound to give problems somewhere and is difficult to debug.